# Applying Matrix in android

Tags: android, matrix

I want to apply matrix to a text view.  I am able to apply the matrix on the `onDraw` method

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(20);

       //transform is the matrix
        canvas.drawBitmap(textAsBitmap("0ps", 26, Color.RED), transform, paint);

    }


    public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
        Paint paint = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        paint.setColor(textColor);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
        int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
        int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
        return image;
    }
```

But the problem is that the if the Translation is greater than the view dimension then it is not possible to see the Translation . if the view has `matchparent` dimension then there is no problem, it working properly.

[image]

if the Translation is greater tan the white screen, it is not able to see it

Comment: What do you mean by "transaction"?

Comment: @gus42: amount of Translation in particular direction

Comment: If your view is smaller than what you paint in it, it is obvious that it is not visible. So what is your desired result?

Comment: if I set setTranslationX(10) and setTranslationY(10) I am able to see the text if it is 100 i am not able to see it. only if the view is match parent. is there is any way to get this result without making the view match parent, because i have some  other view also. i need click event in the below layout. if this view is math parent i am not able to get the click event in the below views that the problem

Comment: Make your view bigger. There are several other possibilities beside match parent - depending on the Layout you are using in your activity/fragment.

Comment: like i said i can't make the view bigger . because i need to get the click on other view in the same layout. i am looking for something else other than making the layout bigger.can u suggest anything else

Comment: you are not using `Matrix` in your code at all, so what `Matrix` are you talking about?

Comment: @pskink: transform is the matrix that i apply .canvas.drawBitmap(textAsBitmap("0ps", 26, Color.RED), transform, paint);

Comment: aha ok, `Canvas#concat`

Comment: i already tried    canvas.concat(transform); but nothing is coming

Comment: @pskink :  I hope u understand my problem

Comment: `Canvas#concat` works just fine, i never had any problems with it

Comment: @pskink:  u r saying that i can directly apply matrix to a canvas using  canvas.concat(transform);. r8. i tried that but nothing happen not even the text